# Creating Bar Charts in Python

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a couple of problems with the Bar Chart that I'm trying to create in python.  My code for the chart looks like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from pylab import *
import calendar

def webshow(img):
    savefig(img,dpi=500)
    print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'
    print '<img width="800" height="400" src="'+img+'" />'

genres = []
n = 0
for c in sorted_list: 
    genres.append(sorted_list[n][0])
    n += 1

grosses = []
a = 0
for c in sorted_list:
    grosses.append(sorted_list[a][1])
    a += 1

clf()
bar(arange(len(grosses)),grosses)
xticks( arange(len(genres)),genres, rotation=80)
webshow("barchart.png")
```

My chart looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ltk9v6xShD1r5te58o1_500.png))</sub>

Basically my main problem is that the values are in decimals with scientific notation.  I want to present them in millions if possible.  Also, I'm not sure how to make it so the genres are not cut off at the bottom.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, I would use a `figure` object to work on: this makes it easier to construct the plot to your liking. To construct your graph, the following should do:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)          # Remark 1
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(arange(len(grosses)), grosses)
ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')       # Remark 2
ax.set_xticks(arange(len(genres)))
ax.set_xticklabels(genres, rotation=80)
savefig('barchart.png', dpi=500)
```

Along with the following remarks:

1. This adjusts the size of your image, in this case it enlarges the bottom to be able to fit your labels. In most cases you roughly know the data you are going to put in, so that should suffice. If you are using matplotlib version 1.1 or higher, you could use the [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout) function to do this automatically for you. The alternative is to calculate the needed size by yourself based on the bounding boxes of all axes labels as shown [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html#automatically-make-room-for-tick-labels), but you need a renderer for this to be able to determine the sizes of all labels.
2. By specifying the label format (using either `sci` or `plain`), you can change the rendering of the values. When using `plain`, it will just render the value as is. See the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format) on this function for more info. Note that you can also use the [`set_yticklabels`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) function's `text` argument to control the formatting further (of course that function is also available for the x axis.