# Making a histogram of string values in python

Tags: python, string, histogram

OK so I have six possible values for data to be which are '32', '22', '12', '31', '21' and '11'. I have these stored as strings. Is it possible for python to sort through the data and just make six bins and show how many of each I have? Or do the inputs to a histogram HAVE to be numerical?

Comment: There is a difference between a bar graph and a histogram. A bar graph is appropriate here, while a histogram is not.

Comment: OK but if I used a bar graph would I have to manually sort through each piece of data to determine which category it was in before plotting? Is there a way of getting it to sort it for me like the histogram does?

Comment: What do you mean by "like the histogram does"? Is there a Python histogram library I don't know about?

Comment: If you have a list of strs you can convert them to ints fairly easily: `listOfInts = map(int,listOfStrs)`

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871338/creating-bar-charts-in-python after following Matts advice (converting all to ints).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
data =  ['32', '22', '12', '32', '22', '12', '31', '21', '11']
dict((x, data.count(x)) for x in data)
```

**Result**

```
{'11': 1, '12': 2, '21': 1, '22': 2, '31': 1, '32': 2}
```

Answer (score 8):

Did you consider using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

```
# python 2.7
>>> l = ['32', '22', '12', '31', '21', '11', '32']
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(l)
Counter({'32': 2, '11': 1, '12': 1, '21': 1, '22': 1, '31': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would be super useful but sadly I seem to be on Python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 2):

```
data =  ['32', '22', '12', '32', '22', '12', '31', '21', '11']
sm = {i:0 for i in ['32', '22', '12', '31', '21','11']}
for i in data:
    sm[i] += 1
print sm
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is a list and you want to count the numbers in a bins. I will use `bins` as a dictionary.

```
bin = {'11': 0, '12': 0, '21': 0, '22': 0, '31': 0, '32': 0}

for element in data:
    if element in bin:  # Ignore other elements in data if any
        bin[element] = bin[element] + 1
```

`bins` dictionary will have frequency of each element in data list. Now you can use `bins` to plot bar graph using graph plot library. May be you can use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871338/creating-bar-charts-in-python?lq=1) to check matplotlib usage for plotting bar graph.

Comment: List comprehension is Pythonic, explicit looping is not.

Comment: People are confused about what is pythonic - it means "easy to write, read and understand in Python" or "idiomatic Python". Your code is idiomatic C/Java/...

Comment: And you claim that this code doesn't obey this definition is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't discuss this further. But I disagree with your claim. Thank you.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968/what-defines-pythonian-or-pythonic